# Python - InvocationError in tox running py.test and coverage test

Tags: python, pytest, coverage.py, tox

My project has the following structure:

```
my_project
|
 setup.py
 tox.ini
 src
   |
   core_functions.py 
   client.py
   server.py
   sql_database.py
   tests.py
```

The `tests.py` file contains the tests for all the function in files `client.py, server.py, sql_database.py, core_functions.py`

Next, I created the `tox.ini` file which I want to use for automation of `py.tests` and `coverage tests`. The structure of the tox.ini file is as follows:

```
[tox]
envlist = py27,cov

[testenv]
commands = py.test -sv --doctest-modules my_project/__init__.py my_project/tests.py


[testenv:py27]
commands = coverage erase
           coverage run --source=my_project -m pytest
           coverage report -m
deps = pytest
```

When I run in the command line `tox` the py.tests succeed, but the coverage tests fail with the following error:

```
============== test session starts ===================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.13, pytest-3.1.1, py-1.4.33, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /Users/xyz/Documents/ProjectGit/MyProject/my_project, inifile:
plugins: cov-2.5.1
collecting 10334 items / 167 errorsERROR: InvocationError: 
'/Users/xyz/Documents/ProjectGit/MyProject/my_project/.tox/py27/bin/coverage run --source=my_project -m pytest'
cov inst-nodeps: /Users/xyz/Documents/ProjectGit/MyProject/my_project/.tox/dist/my_project-0.0.1.zip
cov installed: asn1crypto==0.22.0,attrs==17.2.0,Automat==0.6.0,bitarray==0.8.1,boto3==1.4.4,
botocore==1.5.59,cffi==1.10.0,constantly==15.1.0,coverage==4.4.1,cryptography==1.9,
cycler==0.10.0,docutils==0.13.1,enum34==1.1.6,Fabric==1.13.2,functools32==3.2.3.post2,
future==0.16.0,futures==3.1.1,idna==2.5,incremental==17.5.0,ipaddress==1.0.18,jmespath==0.9.3,
my_project==0.0.1,matplotlib==2.0.2,msgpack-python==0.4.8,numpy==1.12.1,paramiko==2.1.2,
Paver==1.2.4,petlib==0.0.41,py==1.4.33,pyasn1==0.2.3,pybloom==1.1,pycparser==2.17,
pyparsing==2.2.0,pytest==3.1.1,pytest-cov==2.5.1,python-dateutil==2.6.0,pytz==2017.2,
s3transfer==0.1.10,scapy==2.3.3,scipy==0.19.0,six==1.10.0,sphinxmix==0.0.6,
subprocess32==3.2.7,Twisted==17.1.0,zope.interface==4.4.1
cov runtests: PYTHONHASHSEED='3903710496'
cov runtests: commands[0] | py.test -sv --doctest-modules my_project/__init__.py my_project/tests.py
```

How can I fix my tox.ini file to make it work?

Comment: I don't see any error. Insufficient copy/paste?

Comment: @phd Look at the line starting with `collecting 10334 items / 167 errorsERROR`

Comment: Ah, sorry. Seems pytest has found 167 errors at import time. Do pytest test pass without tox?

Comment: @phd Yes, the py.tests all passed without any problems

Comment: Then you need more information to debug this. Look into virtual environments created by tox: is everything installed? Activate an environment and run pytest again to test the environment.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the difference between your two invocations.

In `[testenv]` you're essentially calling:

```
py.test -sv --doctest-modules my_project/__init__.py my_project/tests.py
```

But the equivalent with coverage you're just running:

```
py.test
```

`py.test` with no arguments will recurse from the current directory and attempt to discover tests.  This generally **isn't** what you want (you don't care about testing the stdlib, and all the dependencies you've added to a virtualenv, etc.)

If you add your arguments from your other invocation to your coverage line it will act as you want:

```
coverage run --source=my_project -m pytest -sv --doctest-modules my_project/__init__.py my_project/tests.py
```

Answer (score 0):

If this happens after some modification, you may remove the `.lock` file and let `tox` create it again.